Absolute positioning of tikz markings
I want to add markings to a path in tikz at specific coordinates which lie on the path.
Currently I can only place then relative to the length of the path, or at a fixed distance along it.
For instance, in the following MWE I would like to position an arrow marking at exactly ({-3/sqrt(2)},{3/sqrt(2)+3}), but cannot with the methods currently at my disposal. Currently, there is a black dot there:

\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[
decoration={markings,
%%% METHOD 1 %%%
mark=at position 3cm with {\arrow[red,line width=2mm]{>}},
%%% METHOD 2 %%%
mark=between positions 0 and .85 step 3.2mm with {\arrow[blue]{>}}},
postaction=decorate]
(5,3) -- (0,0) arc[start angle=270, end angle=60, radius=3];
%%% WHERE I WANT THE MARK %%%
\fill[] ({-3/sqrt(2)},{3/sqrt(2)+3}) circle(0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


you could add an regular arrow tip if you know the correct angle.

@cfr I'm only drawing simple curves right now, so this would work. My concern is that later on when I'm working with more complicated stuff, it may be quite tedious to calculate the angles at these points... As mentioned in my other comment, that is a bridge for another day.

maybe look at the s3path stuff, but I don't know whether it would help here or not. (it's just where I would look to see if it did.)

\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (5,3) -- (0,0) arc[start angle=270, end angle=60, radius=3];
\fill ({-3/sqrt(2)},{3/sqrt(2)+3}) circle[radius=0.1];
\draw[green] (0,3) +(135:3) circle[radius=0.1];
\draw[->, red, line width=2mm] (0,3) ++(135:3) ++(45:-4pt) -- +(45:4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This will work for my purposes so I will carry on; that being said, I am curious how this could carry over to more complicated curves. However, that is a bridge for another day.

This methode will work on any curve if you can find the slope at the given point. That is the same as finding the tangent. There are several methods to do that - I suspect that the best way depends on the exact case.

You're right, maybe I could even write a program or use a CAS to find the slopes automatically to save time. I know enough calculus to find the slope of a parametric curve, but my mental energy levels are what hold me back from using it :-)
